# Spark Partitioning Hive Table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am trying to partition the hive table with distinct timestamps. I have a table with timestamps in it but when I execute the hive partition query, it says that it is not a valid partition column. Here's the table:

```
+---+-----------------------+
|id |rc_timestamp           |
+---+-----------------------+
|1  |2017-06-12 17:18:39.824|
|2  |2018-06-12 17:18:39.824|
|3  |2019-06-12 17:18:39.824|
+---+-----------------------+
```

```
spark.sql("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonrestrict")

val tempTable  = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM partition_table")

val df = tempTable.select("rc_timestamp")

val a = x.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")

df.collect().foreach(a => {
  spark.sql(s"ALTER TABLE mydb.partition_table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION 
  (rc_timestamp = '$a')").show()
)}
```

Here's the error which I'm getting:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: rc_timestamp is not a valid partition column 
in table mydb.partition_table.;
```

Comment: Please could you post the table definition ?

Comment: spark.sql("CREATE TABLE part_table (id INT, rc_timestamp  timestamp)")

Comment: Please create a table with partition. Refer this to create a partitioned table https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable

Comment: I already have a table with millions of records in the original table so I was trying to alter the table to add partitions. Isn't this the valid syntax though: "ALTER TABLE mydb.partition_table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION 
  (rc_timestamp = '$a')"

Comment: Its a valid syntax. But you cant use it on a non partitioned table

Answer (score 3):

First thing is check your syntaxes using this [InsertSuite test case](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/InsertSuite.scala) specially [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/InsertSuite.scala#L773)

AFAIK you need msck repair or refresh table

```
spark.sql(s"refresh table tableNameWhereYouAddedPartitions")
```

what it does is it will refresh the existing partitions.

you can go with `spark.sql('MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name')`

There is something called `recoverPartitions` (Only works with a partitioned table, and not a view). This is aliased version of  `msck repair table`. you can go ahead and try this..

see this [ddl.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/command/ddl.scala#L570) seems like its equalent by documentation.
example usage :

```
spark.catalog.recoverPartitions(tableName)
```

Note:
 The RECOVER PARTITIONS clause automatically recognizes any data files present in these new directories, the same as the REFRESH statement does.

Comment: you accepted the answer and you un-accepted again i was just wondering what was the reason for that. Do you mind to tell me the reason? do you want anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the partitioning scheme on a Hive table. This would have to rewrite the complete dataset since partitions are mapped to folders in HDFS/S3/FileSystem.

If you want to change partition scheme, the only options is to create a new table and give partitioning information in the `create table` command. After that you have to insert data into new table from the old table. You can also use the [CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS)) command for the same.

`ALTER TABLE mydb.partition_table ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION <(rc_timestamp = '$a')>` - command only adds new partitions in the metastore for an existing partitioned Hive table. For example, let say you have a table `T1` which is partitioned on column `year`. If you want to make metastore aware about "year=2018", then this command is used.